# How to navigate the breakdown of managerial structure in workplace

Tags: professionalism, management, employer-relations

I'm hired by a Manager **X**. He is under the higher level boss **Z**.
**Z** is the largest share holder of the company and initial mentor of **X**.

A breakdown happened between **X** and **Z**. Because **X** wants to pursue his own interest.
And **X** has become more powerful in the company because of my help.
I personally dislike working with **X** and much prefer working with **Z**.
**Z** has indirectly suggest that I should exclusively devote my time for his project.

To make things worst, **Z** has placed **X** in different building.
But **X** still have strings to pull in **Z**'s office. Like controlling some staffs (me included) that he hired initially,
to work on his project.

**Z** can't officially fired **X** because he still need **X** to do some task for him.

What should I do in this situation?

Comment: What you should do depends very much on what result you are trying to bring about. What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri I want to stay and work happily in this company.

Comment: Yes, so what *specifically* is preventing you from staying and working happily in this company?

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri **X** keep asking me to do his project and threatened me if I don't do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Z has indirectly suggest that I should exclusively devote my time for his project.*

"Indirectly" is not good enough.

You must get **Z** to officially and formally transfer you to his project. **Z** must tell **X** that you no longer report to **X** but now report directly to **Z**.

If **Z** will not do this then he must stop teasing you with "indirect" suggestions.

Right now you work for **X** and if he tells you to work on a project then you must work on that project. Continue to do this while having your conversations with **Z**.

You don't need keep secret that you are trying to transfer to **Z**, but you don't need to announce it to **X** either.

Comment: Breveleri. Thanks. That's exactly the answer I was looking for :-)